# Trimming a Blank String in Java

Tags: java, string

I am trying to run a check to see if a string is just white space. I tried using trim like this:

```
if( dataIn[ i ].trim() == "" )
    {
        throw new MailRecordException( "Line: " + lineNumber + ", Field: "
            + fieldNumber + " :Blank Field" );
    }
```

But it never registers as true. How could I run a check to see if a string is only whitespace?

Comment: Per the duplicate question, you need to use `Object.equals(Object)`  to compare `String`(s). But, for your **specific** case I would suggest you prefer [`String.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--), like `data[i].trim().isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
dataIn[ i ].trim().equals("")
```

instead of

```
dataIn[ i ].trim() == ""
```

`==` tests whether the two operands refer to the same object.

`equals()` (which can be overridden) compares the values of the two objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use equals instead of == for String comparison

```
dataIn[ i ].trim().equals("")
```

Comment: Ah, I feel stupid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
if( dataIn[ i ].trim().length() == 0 ) //check for empty string
{
    throw new MailRecordException( "Line: " + lineNumber + ", Field: "
        + fieldNumber + " :Blank Field" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataIn[ i ].trim().length == 0`

or

`dataIn[ i ].trim().equals("")`